# What is p-value telling us when we calculate correlation using stats.pointbiserialr?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, p-value

I am using stats module from spicy library to calculate the biserial correlation between a categorical and a continuous variable. 
In the output I also get a p-value along with the correlation value. How do I interpret the correlation value in the light of p-value?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col_1': np.random.randint(50,100, size=50), 
        'col_2': np.random.choice([0,1], 50),
        'col_3': np.random.choice(['A','B'], 50)
        })

from scipy import stats
stats.pointbiserialr(df['col_1'], df['col_2'])
```

Output:

```
PointbiserialrResult(correlation=-0.050806559668960444, pvalue=0.7260412034647349)
```

Thank you for helping me understand this!